# xlwt.Style.EasyXFCallerError: section 'fill' is unknown

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, xlwt

I have a data frame in which I am making updations like writing and adding the background colour to a specific cell. It looks fine in `dataframe`. But when I convert `dataframe` to excel, found the below error.

`df.to_excel("test_sheet.xls")` is causing the error.

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scoring_model.py", line 441, in <module>
    pf = ScoringModel()
  File "scoring_model.py", line 12, in __init__
    self.start_scoring()
  File "scoring_model.py", line 185, in start_scoring
    df.to_excel("test_sheet.xls")
  File "D:\Projects\Scoring Model\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\style.py", line 187, in to_excel
    engine=engine)
  File "D:\Projects\Scoring Model\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py", line 662, in write
    freeze_panes=freeze_panes)
  File "D:\Projects\Scoring Model\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 1708, in write_cells
    style = self._convert_to_style(cell.style, fmt)
  File "D:\Projects\Scoring Model\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 1771, in _convert_to_style
    style = xlwt.easyxf(xlwt_stylestr, field_sep=',', line_sep=';')
  File "D:\Projects\Scoring Model\venv\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Style.py", line 733, in easyxf
    field_sep=field_sep, line_sep=line_sep, intro_sep=intro_sep, esc_char=esc_char, debug=debug)
  File "D:\Projects\Scoring Model\venv\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Style.py", line 638, in _parse_strg_to_obj
    raise EasyXFCallerError('section %r is unknown' % section)
xlwt.Style.EasyXFCallerError: section 'fill' is unknown
```

using `python3.5` and `xlwt 1.3` latest.
Does anyone found the same error?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you paste in the `xlwt_stylestr`?

There could be a typo in there [missing a space character?], as I checked the origin of the exception - https://github.com/python-excel/xlwt/blob/master/xlwt/Style.py#L639

Based on the comments, could you try:

```
xlwt_stylestr = 'pattern: pattern solid, fore_colour red;'
```

And then pass it to the `write` callable:
https://xlwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlwt.Worksheet.Worksheet.write
styled.to_excel('styled.xlsx')

Can you try this:

```
def bg_red(val):
    # this will receive each value in the excel
    # so if you want to add conditional logic, you can
    # add here
    return 'background-color: red'

style_obj  = df.style.applymap(bg_red)
style_obj.to_excel('styled_doc.xlsx')
```

Refer this for more:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html

Comment: this is the style string i am adding `'background-color: Red'`, and it worked in data frame.

Comment: tried with the above-displayed method, but not working, it fails in data frame too.

Comment: it's not showing any errors, but no colour is displaying.

Comment: Are you adding the `style` object [xlwt.easyxf(...)] while writing the data?

Comment: nop. I am using `df = df.style.apply(['pattern: pattern solid, fore_colour red;'])` like this.

Comment: and while converting `df.to_excel` is invoking the old issue, now no issues found. but no colour is displaying.

Comment: Then you don't need the `xlwt.easyxf` object.
`df.style.applymap('background-color: red')`
would work fine. Right?

Comment: I have used applymap and apply methods. but customizing based on different conditions are not working.

Comment: shows the same above error from `df.to_excel("test_sheet.xls")`.

Comment: @ArunAugustine, can you try my latest code snippet? I have tested it to generate an excel. You can apply more logic in the function as per requirement.

Comment: the above solution worked by downgrading pandas to 0.20.0, but it won't work with pandas 0.24.2.thanks

Comment: I thought this is available from version 0.17.1 as it shows in the document. It could be some other lib that fails. Anyways good to know that the solution worked. Thanks for accepting my answer.

Answer (score 3):

As lame as it sounds I was having the same difficulty which halted when I changed

df.to_excel("test_sheet.xls")

to

df.to_excel("test_sheet.xls***x***")

FWIW I'm also using 'xlsxwriter'

Comment: Please highlight the change in your answer. You solved my problem even though I could not notice the additional **X** in *xlsx* at first.

Comment: Apologies for that. Corrected.